# How to make the code dynamic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have a small piece of code and I need to make it dynamic. I want to increase the width and height of the code when the sets length increases.

**venn-example.js**

```
if (sets.length >= 0 && sets.length <=24){

    var chart = venn.VennDiagram().width(500).height(500);
}

 else if (sets.length >=25 && sets.length<=50){

    var chart = venn.VennDiagram().width(1000).height(800);
  }
else if (sets.length <=51 && sets.length >=100){

    var chart = venn.VennDiagram().width(1300).height(1300);
}
else if (sets.length <=101 && sets.length<=150){

    var chart = venn.VennDiagram().width(1500).height(1600);
}
else if (sets.length <=151 && sets.length >=250){

    var chart = venn.VennDiagram().width(1700).height(1900);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: When do you increase the size of the set? ... Call this functions whenever you do that and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of arrays (or an array of objects), with each item containing the smaller limit, the larger limit, and the associated `width` and `height` you want. For example:

```
const lengthWidthHeights = [
  // min, max, width, height
  [0, 24, 500, 500],
  [25, 50, 1000, 800],
  [51, 100, 1300, 1300],
  [101, 150, 1500, 1600],
  [151, 250, 1700, 1900]
];
const { length } = sets;
let chart;
const foundItem = lengthWidthHeights.find(([min, max]) => length >= min && length <= max);
if (foundItem) {
  const [,,width, height] = foundItem;
  chart = venn.VennDiagram().width(width).height(height);
}
```

Then, to make changes, all you need to do is change the array items.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about this -  const { length } = sets; that it gives the length